# Rock, Paper, Scissors! game in Python. Output of score and winner not changing

Tags: python, python-3.x

**EDIT:**

**I now realise that this was a bit of a duplicate but user2314737 's answer did help because there was an issue with operator precedence, so I will leave the question up in case it helps someone in the future.**

I am currently trying to program a Rock, Paper, Scissors game in Python. The problem I am faced with, is that when I win, the score doesn't seem to change, and when I do win, the computer still says I have lost. Here is my code:

```
print("Welcome to my Rock, Paper, Scissors! game. Its quite simple. 'R' = Rock, 'P' = Paper and 'S' = Scissors. All of your inputs must begin with a capital letter. Good luck! Here we go!")
import random
Computer_RPS = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"]

def RPS():
    Cpoints = 0
    Upoints = 0
    one = 1
    User_choice1 = input("Rock, Paper, Scissors!...")
    Computer_choice1 = (random.choice(Computer_RPS))
    """
    while (User_choice1 != "Rock" or "Paper" or "Scissors" or "R" or "P" or "S"):
        User_choice1 = input("That value is not valid. Lets try again; Rock, Paper, Scissors!...")
    """
    if User_choice1 == Computer_choice1:
        print("Draw. Getting tense!...")
        print("I chose:" + (Computer_choice1))
        print("The score stands at: " + str(Cpoints) + " to me and " + str(Upoints) + " to you.")
    elif Computer_choice1 == "Rock" and User_choice1 == "S" or "Scissors":
        (Cpoints) + (one)
        print("Good try. Better luck next time!")
        print("I chose:" + (Computer_choice1))
        print("The score stands at: " + str(Cpoints) + " to me and " + str(Upoints) + " to you.")
    elif Computer_choice1 == "Paper" and User_choice1 == "R" or "Rock":
        (Cpoints) + (one)
        print("Unlucky. But that means 1 point to me!")
        print("I chose:" + (Computer_choice1))
        print("The score stands at: " + str(Cpoints) + " to me and " + str(Upoints) + " to you.")
    elif Computer_choice1 == "Scissors" and User_choice1 == "P" or "Paper":
        (Cpoints) + (one)
        print("Unlucky. But that means 1 point to me!")
        print("I chose:" + (Computer_choice1))
        print("The score stands at: " + str(Cpoints) + " to me and " + str(Upoints) + " to you.")
    else:
        print("Well Done! You beat me.  :'-(   Never mind. One point to you.")
        Upoints += 1
    
RPS()
RPS()
RPS()
```

and here is a screen-shot of my code and the output of it:
[My code and its output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrJ8m.png)

Any help will be greatly appreciated by me. Thank you for even just taking your time to read my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an issue with *operators precedence*. Consider this:

```
a=1

if a==3 or 4:
    print("a is equal to 3 or four")
```